# Selenium Webdriver Java - Generate HAR after Click

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, har

I am using Selenium Webdriver + firebug + netExport for capturing the network traffic requests when a website is loaded(Works Fine). I need one more case i.e onClick of a iframe element after the page load I need to generate HAR for the newly opened page. I have tried with the same "driver." but its not working.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

// Wait till Firebug is loaded
Thread.sleep(5000);

// Load test page
driver.get("http://localhost/test.html");

// Wait till HAR is exported
// At this point the HAR is generated "successfully" on page load
Thread.sleep(20000);

List<WebElement> AlliFrameID = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
System.out.println(AlliFrameID.size());

for(int i=0;i<AlliFrameID.size();i++) {
    System.out.println(AlliFrameID.get(i).getAttribute("id"));
}

driver.findElement(By.id(AlliFrameID.get(0).getAttribute("id"))).click();
```

Comment: It would really help if you provided code!

Comment: Show your piece of code which is not working.

Comment: And I have set the right profile preferences for both firebug and netexport. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: You could use [browsermobproxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) to easily create HARs